# Visual Basic Reading Saving Images Into Access

Tags: vb.net

Can someone please give me an explanation to this code, and for your information I am trying to save a picture which is displayed in a picture box and save it to the Microsoft access database, I don't understand what anything means, and especially the 0.

```
 If Not PictureBox1.Image Is Nothing Then

            Dim fsreader As New FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            Dim breader As New BinaryReader(fsreader)
            Dim imgbuffer(fsreader.Length) As Byte
            breader.Read(imgbuffer, 0, fsreader.Length)
            fsreader.Close()
```

Comment: Your code is VB.NET, not VBA

Comment: If you want to know what the parameters to a method mean then the obvious thing to do is to read the MSDN documentation for that method.  There's a Help menu in VS for a reason.

Comment: What does that snippet have to do with MS-Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your snippet code is code to save a binary of picture to `imgbuffer` variable in VB.Net. This snippet code didn't save this images into Ms Access. But...

I will try to explain it, how this code works :

```
If Not PictureBox1.Image Is Nothing Then 'This code for checking if there's any images in the picture box, if it's so run next code.
    Dim fsreader As New FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)  'This variable declared for getting file name, access file and the read mode. And open it using `Filestream` variable, so after it's opened, the length of images will be saved into `fsreader` variable
    Dim breader As New BinaryReader(fsreader) 'This code for reading the binary of images from `fsreader` variable and put the image buffer from range of byte to a variable
    Dim imgbuffer(fsreader.Length) As Byte  'This variable is use to collect image buffer with specified length of binary images from `fsreader` variable.
    breader.Read(imgbuffer, 0, fsreader.Length) 'This code is use for reading binary of images with specified length of byte and put the image buffer into a imgbuffer variable. The number `0` in the brackets means the binary images will be put fully in imgbuffer. Why `0` ? can I use larger than `0` ? yes you can but the image will be corrupt or differ from the original, so you must read the binary images from 0 to the image file size.
    fsreader.Close() 'This is for closing `fsreader` from accessing images file.
```

So, what's next ?

From that snippet code, you can continued it to process the `imgbuffer` variable to save it into `Ms-Access` using some library collection that provided in `VB.Net`, like `OleDB` or anything else. At last, I would prefer using `MemoryStream` to put image buffer and save it into `Bitmap` variable.

Hope this explain your snippet code.

Comment: hey eko junaidi! thank you i get this bit, can i please get your work email or something so you can explain the full code and i really am thank you for the help! and i dont know how to post the whole code here sorry